# Should I port my existing Jammit asset pipeline to the new Rails 3.1 version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

We've implemented Jammit for asset caching, compression and optimization in our Rails application. It's fully integrated with our continuous integration process and works well. That said, I am seeing 3.1 introduces a new canonical asset pipeline based on Sprockets.

Are there advantages to the Sprocket based approach that would merit porting our system? I do not want to spend time converting our system if there are no benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already used Sprocket and Jammit and the main advantage of the Rails 3.1 approach is the complete and native integration of Sprocket, not the gem itself. I'm not a specialist but both gems are great and, for me, equivalent.

The rails 3.1 assets pipeline provide a clean architecture for js and css files and the native use of associated gems (sass, coffee-script, sprocket). If in your app you already have a clean tree for your files and a great integration of your gems, don't change anything !

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looks like I won't switch over at this time.